# Applying css to embeded media player in web page

Tags: html, css, jwplayer, rtmp

I have been trying using media player in web page to stream `RTMP` videos. I have using following code

```html
<embed allowfullscreen="true" src="http://www.focusonthefamily.com/family/JWPlayer/mediaplayer.swf" flashvars="allowfullscreen=true&allowscriptaccess=always&autostart=false&shownavigation=true&enablejs=true&volume=50&file=Test.mp4&streamer=rtmp://192.168.0.102/vod/&image=vid/100_2255.JPG" />
```

Now it showing simple classic jwPlayer. How can i apply styles to it using css  or skin

Comment: You asked how to apply skin, and I answered that. Please mark my answer as the correct answer.

Comment: This is SWF based, you can't override it using CSS.

Comment: You can create your own skin though.

Answer (score 1):

Skins included in the Pro/Premium/Ads editions can be configured by simply inserting the skin name. Here's an example, loading the bekle skin:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
  file: "/upload/myVideo.mp4",
  skin: "bekle"
});
```

Comment: i am using just embedded url with free version. Newbie in embedding media players. Can u help me out how can i add this css in my project

Comment: That would take a long time. You will need to read. Here is a great styled example: http://jsfiddle.net/ramp/nF7Mw/ and here are there docs that you also need to read: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/topics/601064-customization/articles

Answer (score 1):

You're using JW Player 5, which is obsolete. Get JW Player 6. I've found that it's always safest to wrap the player in an outer `<div>`, and apply all styling to that outer `<div>`. So, your setup would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>JW Player</title>
<script src='jwplayer.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Streaming Video</p>
<div id='player'><div id='myElement'>Loading the player...</div></div>
<script>
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "rtmp://example.com/application/mp4:myVideo.mp4",
    image: "/assets/myVideo.jpg",
    height: 360,
    width: 640
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then apply your CSS to the "player" ID.

Are you sure you want to use RTMP? Is this a "live" video feed? If you're just providing MP4's, there's no need to use streaming. RTMP is Flash, which won't work on any mobile, whereas simply providing MP4's will work everywhere.

Comment: Also, flash will be dead in the very near future, chrome will stop supporting it soon.

Comment: Well, no. Chrome will continue to support Flash indefinitely. It's not using NPAPI, which will be turned off by the end of 2015. It's using PPAPI.

Comment: Well, Yes. Chrome IS going to stop supporting flash soon. I will say it again, DO NOT USE FLASH. http://gizmodo.com/future-versions-of-chrome-will-kill-flash-in-the-name-1709212263 they're already forcing advertisers to begin making html5 ads, or they will chrome will convert it itself to html5. Also, Android will not support flash also: http://www.theverge.com/2012/2/7/2782743/adobe-flash-not-supported-chrome-android-browser-android-browser

Comment: Well, no mobile device supports Flash now. Haven't done so for a long time. So that's hardly "news."

Comment: Judging by the OP'S question, I highly expect that stuff to be news to him. FUTURE READERS, DO NOT USE FLASH

Comment: If someone actually needs live streaming, what do you suggest, given the lack of support for HLS in desktop browsers?

Comment: No, I mean NOW, not "real soon now." The first line of the "Formats" section in the Wowza write-up is instructive.

Comment: I need to use streaming server for my project requirements and play it across different platform. Yes i found RTMP not playing on mobile devices either android and ios. Can i use HLS streaming. Will it be play on different platform. I am newbie on streaming servers. your help is highly appreciating ..

Comment: HLS will work on all platforms, but for HLS, you'll need at least a Premium JW Player license. On most desktops, it will use Flash - on mobiles, it doesn't need to. Rather than repeat all of this material, I'll just point you to this starting point: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/topics/564477-streaming/articles